# understanding $_POST and $_SESSION variables

Tags: php

What this php code is doing?

```
$_SESSION['box_status'] = $_POST['box_status'];
```

is it creating an array or what?, i am lost or it is just making a string value and storing it, or it storing multiple values as append?

According to me, it is just creating a string functionality.

Comment: its storing the value from $_POST IN $_SESSION, so it can be used in any page. after using session_start(); hope it explain some thing

Comment: its just storing `$_POST['box_status']` in session cookie .

Comment: @AziBaloch it's called a session _variable_... cookie is a completely different thing

Comment: @AziBaloch $_SESSION - An associative array containing session variables available to the current browser session

Comment: my mistake ... anyway thanks .. @webeno & 4EACH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is setting the value of `$_SESSION['box_status']` to the current value of `$_POST['box_status']`.

[`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) and [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) are reserved variables in PHP; they store the data from a POST operation and session data respectively. They are both associative arrays, which is why they use the `$array['key']` format.

Answer (score 0):

It is taking the POST variable `box_status` and assigning it to the session variable `box_status`

For Reference:

- $_SESSION : http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php
- $_POST : http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what value is sent in POST (e.g. from web form on page).

If there is string in post variable 'box_status' then it saves string into SESSION variable 'box_status'.. if you send array it saves array ..

One important note is that you should serialize/clean POST values before saving them in SESSION

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` and `$_SESSION` are two very special arrays in PHP.

The `$_POST` array will contain all of the *post* data sent to it.

```
<form name='someName' action='thisPage.php' method='POST'>
...
<input type='text' name='someInput'...
...
</form>
```

Sending this form will bring you to the 'thisPage.php' page. Inside of 'thisPage.php', if you were to access `$_POST['someInput']`, that would give you the value that was placed inside the textbox named 'someInput'.

PHP sessions are basically a way of storing information about a user *on the server* while the user continues to browse the page. This is one way of keeping a user logged in while on a site.

Sessions must be started with a `session_start()` call. Once that happens, PHP will check the client's computer for a session id, and pull up the session variables unique to that id (okay, this is just it in a nutshell, feel free to google for more explicit information if you're curious).

Anyways, by setting `$_SESSION['box_status'] = $_POST['box_status'];`, you are saying, "Whatever the user sent to me via the POST data in some input called 'box_status', I want to keep track of that value as they continue to browse my site."

I am, of course, generalizing things here, but you should get the point.

Answer (score 0):

@voyeger

As per your code you have post your data (i.e box_status) from php page & you stored your box_status data in to PHP session.(i.e `$_SESSION['box_status'] = $_POST['box_status']`) .

Basically A session is a way to store information (in variables) to be used across multiple php pages.

Unlike a cookie, the information is not stored on the users computer,it's stored on the server.

So You can use `<?php echo $_SESSION['box_status'];  ?>` to print  your box_status data in to any of PHP page.

Don't forget to start the session (i.e `session_start();`) before print box_status data.